# How can i create side nav bar with 100 tabs in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, single-page-application, angular-routing

i have just starting Angularjs and need some help.
i am working on ANGULAR 4 SPA project where i have side bar with 100 tabs in it . each tab has different content .
[Below is the image of side bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnXxh.png)

. SO i tried simple approach by creating few  components for each tab and adding them in Routes and loading them in   and it works fine .but in this approach i will have to create 100 component for each tab .which i think is not the effecient way . 
So is there any other way /industry standard for this ?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have 100 separated components. I' ve done multiple applications with similar problem. You need one component - SidebarComponent and in there you need to render 100 anchor tags with simple *ngFor. It would look something like this inside sidebar.component.html:

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul id="sidebarnav">
        <li *ngFor="let menu of user.menus">
            <a href="#" [routerLink]="[menu.url]" 
              <span>&nbsp; menu.code </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps!